# I sent Ethereum from Bittrex to ICO smart contract by a mistake

Tags: transactions

Was planning to send Eth to my ERC20 wallet, but by a mistake i sent it directly to the ICO smart contract. But the transaction shows up as a fail and the value says cancelled. I sent the ETH from Bittrex, but the ETH has not come back to my Bittrex wallet. 
How can i get the ETH back?

TxHash:0x942ae095e7f407236f65a3e3b7f027f301b423fb38c9eb87b96d9085315d60cc

Comment: Hi there. You'll have to open a support ticket with Bittrex to find out why this hasn't appeared back in your wallet yet. They should be able to help further. (Flagging this as a third-party support issue.)

Comment: Its been 16 hours, and no reply from Bittrex and no ethereum was returned to my account. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Bittrex customer support. Your ETH went to their hot wallet, which isn't your account that you control. They can see the transaction failure and can refund you in their system.

In the future, though, you should make your own wallet using a hardware wallet like Trezor or the Ledger Nano S, or get a software wallet and do ICO buy-ins from there. That way, when a transaction fails, it'll automatically get refunded back to an account you control, not an exchange.

When a transaction fails, the ether that wasn't spent on gas is automatically returned back to the sending address. In this case, though, that's a hot wallet, not one you control.

Comment: Thanks alot. I opened a support ticket with bittrex. Hopefully they will resolve it and return the ETH to my Bittrex wallet.